# TLA+, pluscal: variable is in a set

Tags: tla+, pluscal

In TLA+ I can write

```
x' \in {TRUE, FALSE}
```

and it will mean, that from this point Model Checker should study two branches, where my variable got different values.
Is there a way to write the same thing in Pluscal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that's not correct TLA+: you want to write either `x' \in {TRUE, FALSE}` or (more preferably) `\E y \in {TRUE, FALSE}: x' = y`.

For PlusCal, you would write

```
\* P-syntax
with y \in {TRUE, FALSE} do \* or {
  x := y;
end with \* or }

\* C-syntax
with y \in {TRUE, FALSE} {
  x := y;
}
```

In all cases you can replace `{TRUE, FALSE}` with the builtin `BOOLEAN`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good answer, especially for the fast reaction!